# Override an application property to undefined/unset

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am not sure if this is a valid question, but I was wondering if this was possible.

A Spring boot project has an application.properties and several profile specific properties. The profile specific properties overrides the defined application.properties with whatever has been defined in the application-profile.properties, and also adds those properties belonging exclusively in the profile specific properties. Illustration below:

application.properties

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

application-profile.properties

```
key1=valueProfile1
key3=valueProfile3
```

When the application starts with this profile, the final properties that it sees are as follows:

```
key1=valueProfile1
key2=value2
key3=valueProfile3
```

In short, you have a union of both the common and profile properties, with the profile property values appending and overriding the common.

But what if, in a god-knows-what scenario, i need a property to be defined in the common application.properties but i need it to be "undefined" when the application starts in one particular profile. Illustration below:

application.properties

```
keySpecial=specialValue
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

application-special.properties

```
key1=valueSpecial1
//unset or undefine keySpecial
keyAlternateSpecial=specialAlternateValue
key3=valueSpecial3
```

Now, when the application starts with this "special" profile, I want it to see the final properties as follows:

```
keyAlternateSpecial=specialAlternateValue
key1=valueSpecial1
key2=value2
key3=valueSpecial3
```

Note that keySpecial is not defined, doesnt even exist, when the application runs in this special profile.

Is this possible?

Note: I know that I can refrain from defining "keySpecial" in the common application.properties, and define them in **all** other profile specific properties. And specify "keyAlternateSpecial" only in "special" profile properties.

**More Info:**

The scenario that made me wonder about this is the spring boot datasource jndi property. [From the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name= # JNDI location of the datasource. Class, url, username & password are ignored when set.
```

The mere existence of this property makes the application ignore the other datasource properties (class,url,username,password) even if they are set.

I am not allowed to remove the jndi property from the "application.properties". But instead I wanted to unset/undefine it and add the other datasource properties (class,url,username,password) in a "special" profile properties.

Comment: I was looking for the same exact thing (same use case with jndi), have you ever found a solution?

Comment: @Fabio Sorry for the late reply. I was not able to find a solution. I will post here in case I find any. Please do post here in case you find something.

Comment: Same issue for something else

Answer (score 12):

You can fake removing spring.datasource.jndi-name from application.property by setting `spring.datasource.jndi-name=false`. This way `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.datasource", name = "jndi-name")` won't enable autoconfiguration class. For details look at ConditionalOnProperty javadoc.

Comment: Thank you this is a great trick and helped me too. I think Spring should support this more directly by looking for an empty value and treating it the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I solved in my use case with by defining the JNDI property in default profile which is activated when no other profiles are defined, in this way during development I can use a different datasources without JNDI.

Here's an excerpt of my `application.yml` file, don't know if this works for you.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
# Default profile, active by default on JBoss since no spring profiles are activated
---
spring:
  profiles: default
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/anagraficaDS
# Development configuration
---
spring:
  profiles: development
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
    username: root
    password: secret
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: This is a workaround. I had mentioned in the question "Note: I know that I can refrain from defining "keySpecial" in the common application.properties, and define them in all other profile specific properties. And specify "keyAlternateSpecial" only in "special" profile properties." . This is just what you did (and me too). I suppose there still is'nt a proper way to undefine/unset a property which has been defined in one of the property sources of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but:

Since **SpringBoot 2.4** a good option would be [profile groups](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.groups).

Put `keySpecial=specialValue` (and other related config) in its own profile - let's call it `special`.
Then add it to the profiles it needs to be in. So if you have profiles `a`, `b`, and `c`, and you only need `special` to be in `a` and `b`, then:

```
spring.profiles.group.profilea[0]=special
spring.profiles.group.profileb[0]=special
```